# Convert negative signed in error number to standard error number

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I have a vague memory of reading about a way to convert error numbers from a format like this `-1073740791` to something meaningful. I am pretty sure it involved converting from a signed Int to something else, and that there was a way to do it in Powershell. But I can't remember enough details to get any results from a search it seems.
Am I just missing some detail, or am I misremembering completely?

Comment: It depends on what type of exception we are talking about, i.e.: for win32exception is pretty easy `[System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception]::new(4)`

Comment: @santiago-squarzon That converts to an error message, which in the two scenarios I am dealing with now (-2147219694 & -1073740791) are both unknown errors. The problem is that these are Errors from an Autodesk installer, and Autodesk is retarded beyond words.

Comment: The error numbers are not ones that are mapped to any standard errors, and while the installer returns an error as a signed Int, the error in their bloated logs are unsigned. So you can't even search THEIR logs for the error number THEY provide, without doing the conversion. But maybe I am remembering this static method, not a way to cast the number itself. Sigh. I really do hate Autodesk. Adobe level of customer hostility, and Trump Cabinet level of incompetence.

Comment: Are you looking for `([int64]-1234567890).tostring('x')?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following to convert those numbers to more Google-searchable message/exception hex numbers:

- `'0x{0:X}' -f -2147219694`  # --> 0x80040712 --> **E_UPDDEPLOY_REBOOT_REQUIRED**
  A system restart is required to complete the installation.
  [Windows Update Agent](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15260.windows-update-agent-error-codes.aspx)
- `'0x{0:X}' -f -1073740791`  # --> 0xC0000409 --> **STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN**
  Very generic error.. Can be caused by corrupted system files.
  See also [STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN doesn’t mean that there was a stack buffer overrun](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190108-00/?p=100655)

Comment: That's more like what I thought I remembered. I assume these are NOT Win32Exceptions, so no way to get that message programmatically? I already have a bunch of non standard Autodesk errors with their new ODIS installer, so maybe I just make a lookup table of their stuff and the stuff in that link. Fussy, but it gets the job done.

Comment: @Gordon `certutil /error 0xC0000409` works at least

Comment: @js2010 Wow. If I asked myself, "which old DOS command line utility might convert a hex error number to a meaningful string", Certutil.exe would NOT have been in my top 10. :)

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74194853/45375) (which deserves the accepted status, because it answers the question as asked):

- It looks like **your error number (status number)** is an **[HRESULT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT)**, as used by many Windows subsystems, notably COM.
- An HRESULT is formally a ***signed*, 32-bit integer**, whose [bits are partitioned into multiple groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT#Data_Structure), containing information such as severity, facility (subsystem), and a facility-specific error code.
- Sine the **hight bit is *always* set if the HRESULT represent an *error* condition** (HRESULTs can also encode multiple *success* conditions, in which the high bit is *not* set), the **resulting integer is technically a *negative number***, and represented as such **in *decimal* format** (e.g, `-1073740791`)

  - However, it is **far more common to represent HRESULT values in *hexadecimal* notation** (e.g., `0xC0000409`), given that such values are **ultimately just *bit fields***.
  - Theo's answer shows how to convert a given `[int]` value containing an HRESULT to its hex representation, which facilitates online searches (see below).

---

As for **(automated) lookup of HRESULT values (and other errors)**:

Here are two ways of looking up a given HRESULT value, both of which accept decimal and hex representations *interchangeably*; additionally, they support lookup by an error's *symbolic name* (or part thereof).

- Option A: Via **[hresult.info](https://hresult.info/)**

  - Note: **While the *lookup* part can be automated, the results open in a *web browser* and are therefore meant for the *human observer***; while you could technically programmatically *scrape* the HTML text returned to extract the relevant information, you're better off with Option B, if that is the intent.
    Conversely, if you type / paste the number *interactively* into the site's search field, you'll get instant feedback and are taken directly to the relevant result page (there'll be no intermediate page with search result(s)).

    ```powershell
    $errNo = -1073740791 # may also be (part of) an error's *name*
    Start-Process "https://www.hresult.info/Search?q=$errNo"
    ```
  - Note: [hresult.info](https://hresult.info/) works best with HRESULT error values, whereas `Err.exe` (below) not only seems to know about additional errors, it also directly supports *general* Windows errors, such as `0x2` for `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`; hresult.info finds that error numerically only via its HRESULT equivalent for the Win32 facility, `0x80070002`
- Option B: Via **`Err.exe`**

  - `Err.exe` is an optional **Microsoft CLI (console application)** that can be downloaded from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100432):

    - The download is single, stand-alone executable that has its version number encoded in the file name; e.g.: `Err_6.4.5.exe`
    - Simply rename the downloaded file to `Err.exe` and place it in one of the directories listed in `$env:PATH`, so you can invoke it by mere name.
    - Programmatically, do something like the following, assuming a `bin` folder in the `$HOME` directory as the target dir. (this command uses a direct download link that locks in the version that is current as of this writing):

      ```powershell
       Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile $Home\bin\Err.exe https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/3/2/432140e8-fb6c-4145-8192-25242838c542/Err_6.4.5/Err_6.4.5.exe
      ```
  - For help, invoke `Err.exe` *without arguments*; additional features include:

    - Outputting to XML (`/:xml`)
    - Limiting lookup to specific header files (e.g., `/nterror.h`)
    - Searching by symbolic *name*, via a *prefix*: by *substring* (e.g., `:BUFFER_OVER`) or by *full* name (e.g., `=STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN` )
  - Sample invocation and result:

    ```powershell
     PS> err -1073740791

     # for decimal -1073740791 / hex 0xc0000409
       STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN                                    ntstatus.h
     # The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in
     # this application. This overrun could potentially allow a
     # malicious user to gain control of this application.
     # 1 matches found for "-1073740791"
    ```

---

##### Function `Get-WinError`

[This Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/0fc086da1af9a72a94cbdb4a59d55230) contains helper function `Get-WinError`, which wraps both lookup ways described above in PowerShell-idiomatic fashion:

- `-Online` performs an online lookup via [hresult.info](https://hresult.info/); on Unix-like platforms, this switch is implied, as only online lookups are supported there.
- By default, lookup is performed via Microsoft's `Err.exe` CLI, which is downloaded on demand, and the results are output as *objects* (`[pscustomobject]` instances).

You can install it directly from the Gist as follows, which defines it for the current session and provides instructions on how to make it available in future sessions (While I can personally assure you that doing so is safe, you should always check the source code first.)

```powershell
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/0fc086da1af9a72a94cbdb4a59d55230/raw/Get-WinError.ps1 | iex
```

**Sample code:**

Note:

- The `Get-WinErr` function is assumed to be already defined.
- Unless `Err.exe` happens to be in your `$env:PATH`, you will be prompted to downloaded, as a one-time setup step (you can skip the confirmation prompt with `-Force`).

```powershell
Get-WinError -1073740791, 0x80070006
```

Output:

```powershell
HexNumber  Name                        Source             Message
---------  ----                        ------             -------
0xC0000409 STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN ntstatus.h         The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malici…
0x80070006 DRM_E_HANDLE                windowsplayready.h 
0x80070006 E_HANDLE                    winerror.h         Invalid handle
```

Note that the above shows that a given error number can be defined in multiple subsystems, although usually with analogous meanings.

Comment: again with the in-depth answer that addresses questions I didn't know enough to ask. And making the argument for stack overflow allowing multiple accepted answers. :)

Comment: @Gordon :) It was an interesting rabbit hole to go down into. I hope the answer will find its audience, whether accepted or not.